# Oracle - Query running very slow

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a simple query which is running for ever. There is one date condition which once I remove, the query comes right back with results. Its a date field in the format '31-MAR-15'. I am not understanding why this condition makes the query so slow. Thanks in advance.

```
SELECT
  substr(a.id, 1, 2)   AS country,
  count(DISTINCT a.id) AS id_count,
  sum(a.amount)        AS amount
FROM table1 a
  JOIN table2 b ON a.id = b.id
  JOIN table3 c ON b.party_id = c.party_id
WHERE a.prod_type = 'INS'
  AND c.acct_type = 'LON'
  AND substr(a.id, 1, 2) = 'US'
  AND a.dump_dt = '31-MAR-15'
  AND substr(id, 4, 8) = '20150303'
GROUP BY substr(a.id, 1, 2);
```

Explain Plan:

```
PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
Plan hash value: 255044277

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                         | Name                   | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                  |                        |     1 |   121 |   125K  (1)| 00:25:08 |
|   1 |  HASH GROUP BY                    |                        |     1 |   121 |   125K  (1)| 00:25:08 |
|   2 |   VIEW                            | VW_DAG_0               |     1 |   121 |   125K  (1)| 00:25:08 |
|   3 |    HASH GROUP BY                  |                        |     1 |    98 |   125K  (1)| 00:25:08 |
|   4 |     NESTED LOOPS                  |                        |       |       |            |          |
|   5 |      NESTED LOOPS                 |                        |     1 |    98 |   125K  (1)| 00:25:08 |
|   6 |       MERGE JOIN CARTESIAN        |                        | 12613 |   800K| 21133   (2)| 00:04:14 |
|*  7 |        TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| TABLE1                 |     1 |    45 |    46   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  8 |         INDEX RANGE SCAN          | DATA_DATE__STG_BACKUP2 |  1040 |       |     6   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   9 |        BUFFER SORT                |                        |   182K|  3564K| 21087   (2)| 00:04:14 |
|* 10 |         TABLE ACCESS FULL         | TABLE3                 |   182K|  3564K| 21087   (2)| 00:04:14 |
|* 11 |       INDEX RANGE SCAN            | BSB_PARTYID_IDX        |    22 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 12 |      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID  | TABLE2                 |     1 |    33 |    10   (0)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   7-filter(SUBSTR(A.ID, 4, 8) = '20150303' AND SUBSTR(A.ID, 1, 2) = 'US'
              AND A.PROD_TYPE = 'INS')
   8 - access(A.DUMP_DT = '31-MAR-15')
  10 - filter(C.ACCT_TYPE = 'LON')
  11 – access(B.PARTY_ID = C.PARTY_ID)
  12 - filter(A.ID = B.ID)
```

Comment: What's the type of `dump_dt`? What indexes do you have? What's the explain plan?

Comment: Have you checked that there is an index on DUMP_DT?

Comment: This is invalid SQL for Oracle, which doesn't support the `AS` keyword for aliasing tables. There's something you're not telling us... As others have stated table DDL and explain plans are _essential_ in order for you to get a good answer, it appears as though you're storing dates as strings, which is always a recipe for disaster and lastly `SUBSTR(ID, 4, 9)` returns 9 characters, not 8, so unless ID is less than 13 characters long I'd expect `SUBSTR(ID, 4, 9) = '20150303'` to always return nothing, which means your query doesn't return anything. Can you please clarify your question?

Comment: dump_dt does have an index

Comment: What is the type of that column?

Comment: how large are the tables? ddl? which indices? whats the plan?

Comment: if dump_Dt is a datetime format the use to_date(...)

Comment: dump_dt is of type DATE. Updated the SQL. Had some typo

Comment: Please add that to your question, along with the relevant indexes, and the explain plan. (And always add that information from the start when you post such questions.)

Comment: SUBSTR(ID, 4, 8) = '20150303' part of the query is fine. It's A.DUMP_DT = '31-MAR-15' that is giving a problem. When I run the explain plan the predicate Information for this filter says access(A.DUMP_DT='31-MAR-15')

Comment: @user2511999 It would help to add the entire explain plan to the question.  Run `explain plan for SELECT ...` and then `select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);` and paste the entire result here.

Comment: Added the Explain Plan for reference

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the optimizer is significantly under-estimating the number of rows returned after applying these 4 predicates on `TABLE1`.

```
A.PROD_TYPE = 'INS'
SUBSTR(A.ID, 1, 2) = 'US'
A.DUMP_DT = '31-MAR-15'
SUBSTR(ID, 4, 8) = '20150303'
```

(Slightly off-topic: it's safer to use an ANSI literal `date '2015-03-31'` instead of the implicitly-converted string `'31-MAR-15'`.  And the statement has a few errors, like missing a condition between the first 2 predicates and missing the `A.` in front of the last predicate.)

First, make sure there are accurate statistics on all tables and see if that changes the explain plan:

```
begin
    dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'TABLE1');
    dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'TABLE2');
    dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'TABLE3');
end;
/
```

The "smart column", `ID`, makes it difficult to estimate the number of rows returned after applying conditions.  If it's too late to change the data model you can at least provide Oracle with some extended statistics to help it deal with the predicates:

```
select dbms_stats.create_extended_stats(user, 'TABLE1', '(SUBSTR(ID, 1, 2))') from dual;
select dbms_stats.create_extended_stats(user, 'TABLE1', '(SUBSTR(ID, 4, 8))') from dual;
```

I'm guessing that `SUBSTR(A.ID, 1, 2) = 'US'` is a popular value, but without the extended statistics Oracle won't know that.  The extra histogram may significantly increase the cardinality.  Then the optimizer wouldn't choose the Cartesian join between two unrelated tables.

Answer (score 1):

I've simplified condition in WHERE clause over **A.ID** field

```
A.ID LIKE 'US_20150303%'
```

has the same effect as

```
substr(a.id, 1, 2) = 'US' AND substr(id, 4, 8) = '20150303'
```

and, in case column **A.ID** was indexed, the fact of applying **SUBSTR(a.ID,..)** function makes the index useless.

On the other hand, **a.dump_dt** seems to be a DATE type column, so a preferred way to apply a filter on this column could be

```
a.dump_dt = TO_DATE('31-MAR-15', 'DD-MON-RR')
```

instead of

```
a.dump_dt = '31-MAR-15'
```

The latter depends primarily on NLS_DATE_FORMAT of the Oracle client that runs the query and in some cases could negativally affect the performance by ignoring the use of an index over **a.dump_dt**.

So the rewritten query looks like this:

```
SELECT
  SUBSTR(A.ID, 1, 2)   AS country,
  COUNT(DISTINCT A.ID) AS id_count,
  SUM(A.amount)        AS amount
FROM table1 A
  JOIN table2 b ON A.ID = b.ID
  JOIN table3 c ON b.party_id = c.party_id
WHERE A.prod_type = 'INS'
  AND c.acct_type = 'LON'
  AND A.ID LIKE 'US_20150303%'
  AND A.dump_dt = TO_DATE('31-MAR-15', 'DD-MON-RR')
GROUP BY SUBSTR(A.ID, 1, 2);
```

Comment: Hi there, can you please edit your answer to explain what this query does and how it fixes the problem asked about? Code only answers are discouraged, and are subject to deletion. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use oracle hints to stabilize selection plan or you can use that trick:

```
....
And A.DUMP_DT+0 =  to_date('31-MAR-15','dd-mon-    rr')
...
```